# Как правильно сгенерировать ключ openssl для ISPmanager?

Tags: ssl, openssl

Собственно, как правильно сгенерировать ключ openssl'ем для ISPmanager'а? Какие файлы и какого формата нужно получить от openssl для того, чтобы потом самоподписанный ключ вставить в ISPmanger?

P.S. Я понимаю, что можно внутри менеджера генерировать, но мне нужно этот ключ иметь в виде файлов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для установки самописного SSL вам просто надо зайти в панель IPSManager, в раздел "Настройки веб сервера" дальше в выпадающем меню открыть "SSL сертификаты", после нажимаете "Добавить" и уже на открытой странице выбераете "Самоподписанный сертификат"  а дальше уже 'методом тыка' активируйте сертификат.

Comment: Спасибо, это как бы очевидно... Но мой вопрос звучит немного иначе.

Comment: ну, после очевидной генерации SSL сертификата, вы можете зайти в дирикторию /var/www/httpd-cert/www-root/  (насколько помню) и там будут находиться ваши файлы для ssl 
vashdomain.ru.ca
vashdomain.ru.crt
vashdomain.ru.crtca
vashdomain.ru.key